# Regex How can I find names only written in upper-case letters(mandatory), and the names may also contain numbers, literal spaces, and hyphens

Tags: regex, mongodb

If I want to find "KFC", "EU 8RF", and IK-OTP simultaneously, what should the code look like?

My code is :

```
db.business.find({name:/^[A-Z\s?\d?\-?]*$/}, {name:1}).sort({"name":1})
```

but it will return the name that is whole number, such as 1973, 1999. How should I improve my code? TIA

Comment: Will the name always start with a letter?

Comment: Why do you have multiple `?` in the character set? If you want to allow the `?` character you only need it one time. It's not an "optional" quantifier inside `[]`, it's just an ordinary character.

Comment: The name will start with either letter or number, such as 350 BAR, BAR 350.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know the correct use of "?".

Comment: In that case you need to use a lookahead to require a letter.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead to require at least one letter.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z\d\s-]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/FDuhoG/1)

Comment: It works, Thank you so much!!! And by the way, could you please tell me how can I find just one word, but this word is not equal to "test"?

Comment: Haven't tested, but something like `\b(?!test)\w+\b`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?=[\d -]*[A-Z])[A-Z\d]+(?:[ -][A-Z\d]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AazwpI/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[\d -]*[A-Z])` - a positive lookahead that requires an uppercase ASCII letter after any zero or more digits, spaces or hyphens immediately to the right of the current location
- `[A-Z\d]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `(?:[ -][A-Z\d]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a space or `-` and then one or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.